# Run Gwt Application on Apache web server

Tags: apache, gwt, web

I want to run and debug my gwt application in remote environment.like combination of gwt + apache web server for
 ie. i am running and debugging my application like http://ServerName/gwtapp.html?gwt.codesvr=localhost:9997

where as apache server document root is set on my workspace/application/war

can any one help me to configure apache server to configure this type of environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be sufficient to add the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive to your Apache config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot /xxx/workspace/application/war

</VirtualHost>
```

On Linux machines the apache config can be found in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default

Answer (score 1):

Here us the good link which will let you know how to configure Eclipse and your web server to run GWT application in debug mode,

http://rmapper.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/gwt-development-mode-with-hot-deployed-glassfish-in-eclipse-2/